# Why does this implicit type conversion in C# fail?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

## Background:

Let's assume I've got the following class:

```
class Wrapped<T> : IDisposable
{
    public Wrapped(T obj)  { /* ... */ }

    public static implicit operator Wrapped<T>(T obj)
    {
        return new Wrapped<T>(obj);
    }

    public void Dispose()  { /* ... */ }
}
```

As you can see, it provides an implicit type conversion operator for `T` → `Wrapped<T>`. Ultimately, I would like to be able to use this class as follows:

```
interface IX  { /* ... */ }

class X : IX  { /* ... */ }

...

IX plainIX = new X();

using (Wrapped<IX> wrappedIX = plainIX)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

## Problem:

However, the type conversion in the above `using` clause fails. While I can assign a `new X()` directly to `wrappedIX`, I am not allowed to assign anything of type `IX` to it. The compiler will complain with the following error:

> *Compiler error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'IX' to 'Wrapped<IX>'. An explicit onversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

I don't understand this. What's the problem here?

Comment: compilable if replace "IX plainIX = new X();" with "X plainIX = new X();"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's because `IX` is an interface. The compiler thinks that maybe a value of type `IX` could already be derived from `Wrapped<IX>` (even if `Wrapped<T>` is sealed) so it doesn't use the conversion.

The details are quite complicated, in sections 6.4.3 and 6.4.4 of the C# 3.0 spec. Basically because `IX` is an interface, it's not "encompassed by" any types, which means a later step in 6.4.4 fails.

I suggest you create a non-generic type `Wrapped` with this method:

```
public static Wrapped<T> Of<T>(T item)
{
    return new Wrapped<T>(item);
}
```

Then you can just write:

```
using (Wrapped<IX> wrappedIX = Wrapped.Of(plainIX))
```

Basically conversions can be a bit tricky for various reasons - simple methods are generally easier to understand, IMO.

Comment: This will work with C#4, when `T` is properly  decorated with `out`, or doesn't it work for implicit casting?

Comment: @Dykam: You're assuming that `T` *can* be used covariantly. I'm also not sure what you mean by "this" - but as the type of `plainIX` is `IX` rather than `X`, I don't believe the original code would work out of the box.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. Then I missed that part. Implicit conversions get messy quickly in any case.