# Implicit conversion of T to ActionResult<T> does not work for some types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In asp.net core 2.1, `AsctionResult<T>` is introduced, and an implicit type conversion is defined from `T` to `ActionResult<T>`

In my code, I get an error for some conversions. For instance:

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.IEnumerable>'
```

While the same conversion is working fine for other types. I also get this error for a couple of types defined in my code.

The code for the above error is:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> GetByFilter([FromBody]EntityListRequest request)
        {
            return await _entityHandler.GetByFilter(request);
        }
```

where `_entityHandler.GetByFilter()` is:

```
Task<IEnumerable> GetByFilter(EntityListRequest request);
```

Comment: Does it work if you return `IEnumerable<T>`?  It seems strange that you're returning the non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Brad I just tested and got the same error. The reason for returning the non-generic `IEnumerable` is that the actual type of the enumerable members is not known at compile time. It depends on some properties of the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>> has to return a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742520/actionresultienumerablet-has-to-return-a-listt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Apparently this will fail for (some?) interfaces. More information is provided in this QA: [Why does this implicit type conversion in C# fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2526130/742775)

A workaround is to use the constructor of ActionResult:

```
            return new ActionResult<IEnumerable>(myData);
```