# ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>> has to return a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionresult, asp.net-core-2.1

Take the following code using ASP.NET Core 2.1:

```
[HttpGet("/unresolved")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UnresolvedIdentity>>> GetUnresolvedIdentities()
{
   var results = await _identities.GetUnresolvedIdentities().ConfigureAwait(false);
   return results.ToList();
}
```

I would have thought since `GetUnresolvedIdentities()` returns `IEnumerable<UnresolvedIdentity>` that I could just return

```
return await _identities.GetUnresolvedIdentities().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Except I can't, as I get this error:

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Infrastructure.Models.UnresolvedIdentity>'`
>   to
>   `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Infrastructure.Models.UnresolvedIdentity>>'`

I need the `.ToList()`, which is annoying as it's 2 lines rather than 1.

Why can't `ActionResult<T>` figure out that `GetUnresolvedIdentities()` returns an `IEnumerable<>` and just return that?

The signature of `GetUnresolvedIdentities` is:

```
Task<IEnumerable<UnresolvedIdentity>> GetUnresolvedIdentities();
```

Comment: Because `IEnumerable` is different than `IEnumerable<T>`. Either change `_identities.GetUnresolvedIdentities` return type or your controller return type.

Comment: Why not `return await _identities.GetUnresolvedIdentities().ConfigureAwait(false).ToList();`, if the "two lines" is the only thing bothering you?

Comment: @Corak because you can't `task.ToList()`. `(await task).ToList()` would work though

Comment: @VladiPavelka - yes, of course, thank you. ^_^

Comment: You can wrap it around in ActionTask with the Ok helper method: `return Ok(await _identities.GetUnresolvedIdentities());`. P.S. you shouldn't call `.ConfigureAwait(false)` inside the controllers, unless you're 100% certain about the consequences (even though its not that much of an issue these days as it was in legacy ASP.NET). Its advised to always use it in **general purpose libraries** where its unknown in which context the library will be used

Comment: @Tseng, good catch on the COnfigureAwait(false). Thanks

Comment: You actually don’t need to use `ConfigureAwait` anywhere with ASP.NET Core since it does not have a synchronization context.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Take this documentation from msdn:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type

> C# doesn't support implicit cast operators on interfaces.
>   Consequently, conversion of the interface to a concrete type is
>   necessary to use `ActionResult<T>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can resolve this in a relatively tidy way by using `Ok(...)`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyDTOObject>> Get() => Ok(Repo.GetObjects());

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyDTOObject>>> GetAsync() => Ok(await Repo.GetObjectsAsync());
```

Which assuming that `GetObjects()` and `GetObjectsAsync()` return a `IEnumerable<MyDTOObject>` and `Task<IEnumerable<MyDTOObject>>` respectively - allows you to skip `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync()`.